# find number of detected devices in tensorflow

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, tensorflow

As the title already says I want to find out the number of devices (cpus or gpus) that tensorflow is able to detect or make use of.

The reason for this question is because I'm running keras with tf backend on a machine with multiple cpus, but it uses only a single CPU at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this bug report regarding CPU scaling ; https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/583

It was supposedly resolved with change ab02c5, issued at the beginning of May 2016. Try building tensorflow from source to get all the latest updates, which are most likely not in the stable version.