# Why does TensorFlow only find one CPU device despite having multiple cores?

Tags: python, tensorflow

as far as I understood TensorFlow creates one device per core. (source: https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-white-paper-notes: *NOTE: To reiterate- in this context, "single device" means using a single CPU core or single GPU, not a single machine. Similarly, "multi-device" does not refer to multiple machines, but to multiple CPU cores and/or GPUs. See "3.3 Distributed Execution" for multiple machine discussion.*)

My computer has four cores but it only recognises one:

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib 
>>> print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
[name: "/cpu:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
bus_adjacency: BUS_ANY
incarnation: 13835232998165214133
]
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It looks like this is a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296064/find-number-of-detected-devices-in-tensorflow, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/583
See if rebuilding the latest tensorflow version from source helps?

Comment: Cpu:0 is a device representing all cores on machine

Answer (score 6):

By default `cpu:0` represents all cores available to the process. You can create devices `cpu:0`, `cpu:1` which represent 1 logical core each by doing something like this

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 2},
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=2,
                        intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Then you can assign to devices as

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  # ...

with tf.device("/cpu:1"):
  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The assignment works. However, for everyone else: pay attention with print(device_lib.list_local_devices()) as it still only lists one CPU device.

Comment: What do these values mean and why did you choose the values like that?: inter_op_parallelism_threads=2, intra_op_parallelism_threads=1

Comment: inter_op_parallelism_threads is the size of Eigen threadpool, intra_op_parallelism_threads controls how many ops can be launched in parallel

Comment: Today's version of https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu seems to suggest the `with` construct can be used without the `device_count` etc being configured, unless I'm missing something from the site. In practice, however, it wakes all 4 GPUs before running the operation only on the designated one.

Comment: How can I restrict TensorFlow to use only and only 1 core of a CPU?