# Using multiple CPU Cores with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cpu-usage

**I am running a tensorflow training on a Linux machine with 4 cores.
When checking the cpu utilization with htop, only one core is fully utilized, whereas the others are utilized only with ~15% (image below shows a screenshot of htop).**

How can I make sure TF is using all CPUs to full capacity?
I am aware of this issue ["Using multiple CPU cores in TensorFlow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507748/using-multiple-cpu-cores-in-tensorflow) - how to make it work for Tensoflow 2?

[image: htop-screenshot].

I am using the following code to generate the samples:

```
class WindowGenerator():

    def make_dataset(self, data, stride=1):
        data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
        ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
            data=data,
            targets=None,
            sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
            sequence_stride=stride,
            shuffle=False,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,)
      
        ds = ds.map(self.split_window)
      
        return ds


    @property
    def train(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.train_df)
    
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.val_df)
    
    @property
    def test(self):
        return self.make_dataset(self.test_df, stride=24)
```

I'm using the following code to run the model training. sampleMgmt is of Class WindowGenerator. early_stopping defines the training termination criteria.

```
history = model.fit(sampleMgmt.train, epochs=self.nrEpochs,
                  validation_data=sampleMgmt.val,
                  callbacks=[early_stopping],
                  verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did two things outside my code to make TF use all CPUs availible.

1. I used a SSD instead of a HDD
2. I used the Tensorflow Enterprise Image, provided in Google Cloud, instead of the Deep Learning Image

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={"CPU": 8})
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893161/why-does-tensorflow-only-find-one-cpu-device-despite-having-multiple-cores))

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the sess object to start training. (Actually I thought that was a TF1.x syntax)

Comment: In the link you referenced to, Yaroslav is mentioning that "By default cpu:0 represents all cores available to the process.". 
Does this mean, that it is perfectly normal, that htop only shows high load in one cpu, and not all of them?